# How to convey to Bazel several correct implementations of lower level library?

Tags: bazel

I have 2 implementations of a library that implement a common set of header files (libraries *X* and *Y*).

I have a middleware library (*Z*) that can be used with either of the aforementioned libraries (*X* or *Y*). Users in my repository will know which version they will want.

What's the best way to convey this in *Bazel*? I'd like to only compile library *Z* once, and at link time the `cc_binary` rule needs to list *X* or *Y* as a dependency as well. The `cc_library` rule needs to list a dependency though.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way how this can be done is by telling Z about both X and Y and using `select` in its deps to pick the right one. We discussed a feature similar to what you propose, but no actual development is planned.

Comment: It could technically, if you wrote your own rules, but I'm not sure this is something we would encourage due to the combinatoric explosion of the configured target graph.